# How extended (4MB) and regular (4KB) paging coexist?

Tags: linux-kernel, memory, virtual-memory

On x86 architecture, "Extended paging" allows page frames (physical memory) to be 4 MB instead of 4 KB.

The book "Understanding the Linux Kernel, 3rd" at chapter 2 "Memory Addressing", sub-chapter "Paging in Linux", section "Kernel Page Tables", explains that for the final kernel Page Table when RAM size is less than 896 MB:

> [...]the kernel can address the RAM by making use of large pages (see the section
>   "Extended Paging" earlier in this chapter).

However, in the section "Extended Paging" (sub-chapter "Paging in Hardware"), it is written :

> Extended paging coexists with regular paging.

I don't actually get how extended and regular paging coexist. Can please someone explain those questions:

- In which cases the kernel uses 4 MB pages? or 4 KB pages?
- Which page frame size will be used for kmalloc operations? for vmalloc?
- If we assume that the initial code & data (kernel's segments, provisional Page Tables, and 128 KB for dynamic data) fit in the first 8 MB of RAM (as the example given by the book), what if the real amount of code & data is 5MB only: will the kernel waste 8 - 5 = 3 MB?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128213/how-is-page-size-determined-in-virtual-address-space?rq=1 seems to cover this topic.

Comment: [Multiple page sizes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_%28computer_memory%29#Multiple_page_sizes)

Answer (score 2):

> 1.  In which cases the kernel uses 4 MB pages? or 4 KB pages?

Application can apply for huge page, kernel will not determine the page size unless compile the PAGE_SIZE into the kernel source code. Using mmap flags can determine the page size in the source code of application.

> 2.  Which page frame size will be used for kmalloc operations? for vmalloc?

kmalloc use default page size in Linux kernel, that is PAGE_SIZE in the kernel, which is compiled or runtime determined. Same for vmalloc.

> 3.  If we assume that the initial code & data (kernel's segments, provisional Page Tables, and 128 KB for dynamic data) fit in the first 8 MB of RAM (as the example given by the book), what if the real amount of code & data is 5MB only: will the kernel waste 8 - 5 = 3 MB?

The size of waste memory is determined by PAGE_SIZE and the data, if page size is 4MB, data is 5MB, the wasted memory size will be (PAGE_SIZE*N) - 5MB= 3MB.