# What is the minimum swap size for hibernation?

Tags: linux, swap, power-management, suspend, ram

Consider the following scenario: I'm running a Linux system with a large amount of RAM. Swap is disabled, except for hibernation. When hibernating, let's assume that RAM data can not be compressed before writing it to disk. What is the exact minimum swap size necessary to guarantee successful hibernation?

Naively, I'd think that it's sufficient if the swap size equals RAM size. However, I've read [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/693953/on-linux-what-is-the-technical-minimum-size-for-a-functional-swap-partition) that swap has some size overhead, so it doesn't mirror RAM content one to one. Furthermore, I would think that hibernation may require storing the internal states of some hardware components to swap for later reproduction. So, is it even possible to calculate a minimum swap size which guarantees successful hibernation in every possible system state? If it's not possible to give a specific minimum, is there at least some size which is guaranteed to always be sufficient (e.g. twice the RAM size)?

Comment: Some info: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2478996

Comment: In theory, any swap you add could be fully utilized to the brim, so a "guarantee in every possible system state" does not exist. In practice, it's rarely an issue. You got plenty of (free) RAM that doesn't even go into your hibernation image. Plus it's LZO compressed, so the image size is smaller than used RAM. If you don't skimp on the size too much it will "just work" for most people. Depends on your use case.

Comment: I'm assuming that swap use is limited to hibernation only.